# Unable to pass date parameter in c# for database query

Tags: c#, ado

I am trying to pass the new DateTime 2013-09-22 into the following, however it shows that there is a error in my sql syntax.
Any idea?

```
DateTime WeekEnding = new DateTime(2013, 9, 22);
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
    @"select WeekEnding, sum(Total) as Total " +
     "from Data  where WeekEnding = '@WeekEnding' " +
     "group by WeekEnding", 
     myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@WeekEnding", SqlDbType.DateTime);
myCommand.Parameters["@WeekEnding"].Value = WeekEnding;
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Combined : " + myReader["Total"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" doesn't help us understand the problem very well. Are there any errors or are you just not getting the result you expected?

Comment: Have you tried the SQL statement directly on the SQL server to ensure it works there?

Comment: I am not able to compile this and it appeared to be my SQL syntax problem as it works in SSMS. As most people pointed out, The variable @WeekEnding should have no single quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes around your parameter. Parameters are always unquoted, even if the representation of the actual data would have been quoted in the sql string.

On a sidenote, please consider using-blocks for your IDisposable database objects like SqlDataReader, SqlCommand and others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to enclose your parameter in single quotes, it will work without it.

Also, when working with dates you have to remember that a `DateTime` object has a date and a time component, so you would be better off using `>=` and `<=` together, unless you know for certain that the fields in your database will always have the time component set to midnight.

Try this:

```
DateTime WeekEnding = new DateTime(2013, 9, 22);
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(
    @"select WeekEnding, sum(Total) as Total " +
     "from Data  where WeekEnding >= @WeekEnding AND WeekEnding <= @WeekEnding" +
     "group by WeekEnding", 
     myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@WeekEnding", SqlDbType.DateTime);
myCommand.Parameters["@WeekEnding"].Value = WeekEnding;
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Combined : " + myReader["Total"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes around `'@WeekEnding'` from the query. Query text should be like that:

```
@"select WeekEnding, sum(Total) as Total " +
 "from Data  where WeekEnding = @WeekEnding " +
 "group by WeekEnding",
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use String.Format() Method to achieve your goal.

for example :

```
string query = @"select WeekEnding, sum(Total) as Total 
                                        from Data  where WeekEnding = {0} 
                                         group by WeekEnding";
string sql = String.Format(query,WeekEnding);
//then 
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql , myConnection);
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); 
while (myReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Combined : " + myReader["Total"].ToString());
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Please don't advise people to open gaping security holes in their software. Read up on SQL-Injection to get details about why this is a bad idea.

Comment: I know about SQL-Injection. Actually it will be so dangerous if the @WeekEnding parameter value is coming from a user input. Since it is a DateTime instance , I do not think it is that bad idea. However thanks for you comment. ;